# como faço em php para pegar todos os caracteres especificos de uma string

Tags: php

eu preciso pegar todos caracteres 'SD' de dentro de uma string eu estou usando a função php strpos e depois fazendo um substr na posição encontrada na string, porém preciso pegar de todos pois a posição é variadas.

```
//trazendo a darkness do template no banco
    $label = substr($qry['label_tpl_content'],7,5);
    $labels = substr($qry['label_tpl_content'],15,5);
    echo "<br>";
    $pos =  strpos($qry['label_tpl_content'],"SD");
    echo $pos;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $label."<br>";
```

essa variavel vem alguma mais ou menos assim

XA^35~SD10N^T0~SD13 por exemplo mais nem sempre esta na mesma posição.

Comment: Você quer saber quantas vezes aparece a palavra 'sd', ou as suas posições?

Comment: vc quer contar o numero? ou quer remover as ocorrencias?

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer apenas contar a quantidade de ocorrências dentro da String, sugiro que a utilização da função **substr_count()**

[Documentação PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php)